# Storing lots of attachments in single CouchDB document

Tags: couchdb, archive, tar, attachment

**tl;dr** : Should I store directories in CouchDB as a list of attachments, or a single tar

I've been using CouchDB to store project documents. I just create documents via Futon and upload them directly from there. I've also written a script to bulk-upload directories. I am using it like a basic content repository. I replicate it, so other people on my team have a copy of the repository.

I noticed that saving directories as a series of files seems to have a lot of storage overhead, so instead I upload a `.tar.gz` file containing the directory. This *does* significantly reduce the size of the document but now *any* change to the directory requires replicating the entire tarball.

I am looking for thoughts or perspective on the matter.

Comment: Have you tried to compress every single file separately?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really depends one what you want to achieve. I will try and provide some options for you to consider.

Storing one tar.gz will save you space, but it does make it harder to work with. If you are simply archiving it may work for you.

Storing all the attachments on one document works well for couchapps. The workflow is you mess around with attachments until you are ready to release the application, then there is not a lot of overhead for replication, because it is usually one time. It is nice that they are one one document because they all move/replicate as one bundle. Downsides for using this approach for a content management system are that you can get a lot of history baggage that you have to compact on your local couch. Also you will get a lot of conflicts during replication between couches, and couch will keep conflicts around for you to resolve. Therefore if you choose this model, you should compact frequently to reduce disk size.

For a content management system, I might recommend using one document per attachment. That would give you less conflicts. There will be a slight overhead as each doc will have some space allocated for the doc itself, but the savings in having to do frequent compaction and/or conflict resolution will be better.

Hope that gives you some options to weigh out.

Comment: I think I will either use a single document per attachment, be it a single file or a tar.gz bundle. I think managing conflicts and compacting is enough to scare me away from too many attachments per document.